# How to fix USB keyboard that sporadicly stops working on a Mac Mini?

Tags: keyboard, usb, mac-mini

I have an Intel Mac Mini (`Macmini8,1`) with an Apple USB keyboard plugged directly in to one of the USB A ports on the back of the Mac Mini. I use a USB mouse attached to the hub on the Mac Mini.

Occasionally and sporadically the USB keyboard stops working at all. This sometimes happens multiple times an hour, sometimes not for hours at all. Sometimes it lasts for just a second or two, sometimes for a minute or more. The issue always goes away on it's own and there's seemingly nothing I can do to effect it.

When the issue happens, no keyboard input is detected -- normal keystrokes are not detected, command keys do not work, the Caps Lock light will not illuminate when the key is pressed, nothing. Also, the USB mouse will stop working. It sometimes happens in the middle of typing text (for example, it happened for a second when typing this question)

If using a *bluetooth* mouse, the mouse is unaffected and the Mac can be used normally. CPU is not high (it was under 4% last time) and if I look in System Information when this is happening I *do* see the keyboard listed under "USB"...

Currently running Mac OS Monterey (12.0.1) but this happened with Mac OS X Catalina (10.15) as well. I recognize that the next step may be doing a clean install and debugging that way, but I'd prefer to debug using my current OS considering how sporadically this happens.

Issue happens with two different Apple keyboards, and they work perfectly fine on a MacBook Pro; so I am sure the keyboard is not the problem.

Looking for any advice of logs to check, debugging to do, etc... I've checked `dmesg` and didn't see anything useful, and I've looked in the Console but these days there's *so much stuff* logged in the Console that the signal to noise is terrible and I don't even know what I'm looking for...

Has anyone sen this before? What could cause my USB Apple keyboard to sporadically stop working and how can I debug further?